# How to get data of a child in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my database tree structure like this:

[image]

Please tell me how do I get the value of "username" if I have the value of "userid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I get the value of "username" if I have the value of "userid"

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, username);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
hisoka
```

Comment: @ Alex Mamo Suppose I already have specific uidRef that I want then can I access the value of username directly i,e without taking a datasnapshot. Example: Suppose I have "8y9Z3ng8lMatFtNYzbnsX3e9cGI2" (this is unique userid of hisoka) then can I directly access the field username

Comment: Everything in Firebase is about listeners. There is no way in which you can get the value of your `username` property directly, without using a listener. That's the way you can get the data from the database.

Comment: Yeah I did it thanks for the help you really helped me alot

Comment: I tried the above code, I modified only one line i,e  DatabaseReference uidRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(sender);  And my "sender" contains current user's "uid" but iam always getting "null" in my logcat my username is not being printed.what might be the reason and Iam quite sure that "sender" has correct value

Comment: Try to log the value of sender and see if it is the same as in your database. You can also try to hardcode the value, to be sure.

Comment: Yeah I did it and it is the exact same one .why am I getting this null value.

Comment: Without seeing the code that you are using, I cannot be much of a help. Please add it to your question.